# Java, Client-Side NTLM Authentication

Tags: java, http, authentication, ntlm

I'm charged with building an app health monitoring system, and one of the requirements is to check both if our various java services are up and if our reverse proxy is up. The reverse proxy is a .NET application that gets a user's AD Groups and passes them along to our apps via a header for monitoring/security reasons.

Obviously the rinky dink input and output stream http request isn't enough, but I haven't found information or guides about client-side NTLM authentication for Java.

I'm guessing there's a library (probably Oracle or Apache) that provides a handler that can do this, but I have come up empty trying to find it. Please help.

Comment: Unclear, probably off-topic because you're searching for a library, not for help. (When I put 'ntlm java' into the google I get all sorts of libraries mentioned, what did you search?)

Comment: 1) Knowing what libraries are applicable to a problem and telling someone IS helpful.

2) Did you find the client-side ones? All I can find is server-side.

Comment: There is none, it is proprietary software. You can search for custom, partially reverse-engineered solutions or implement it yourself, the specs are online. Use Kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

Great code and context can be found here, for client side. 
http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#appendixD